# Cut and Fail in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

Consider the following code:

```
a(X) :- b(X),!,c(X),fail.
a(X) :- d(X).

b(1).
b(4).
c(1).
c(3).

d(4).
```

The query `a(X).` produces

```
1 ?- a(X).
false.

2 ?-
```

but with this code

```
a(X) :- b(X),!,c(X).
a(X) :- d(X).

b(1).
b(4).
c(1).
c(3).

d(4).
```

The query `a(X).` results in :

```
1 ?- a(X).
X = 1.
```

So my question is, why does the `fail/1` produces false? it is supposed to force backtracking, right ? then `b(1)` and `c(1).` would be checked, I think, so why does it fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it fails because `fail` *must* fail.

The cut removes alternatives, then forbids values that otherwise would be 'returned' by means of `X` binding. Try

```
a(X) :- b(X),c(X),fail.
...
```

you'll get

```
?- a(X).
X = 4.
```

Comment: But the `cut/1` checks only `X=1` , doesn't it ? then it would check both `b(1)` and `c(1)` . Am I wrong ?

Comment: cut it's a nasty theme. See if you can follow the [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=!/0)

Answer (score 3):

example :

```
a(X):- b(X),!,fail. %is the same as \+ a(X):- b(X).
```

the merge of "!" and "fail" gives you **the negative of a(X)**.

its called the **Negation by Failure**.

Answer (score 1):

As @CapelliC said , the rule of `a(X) :- b(X),!,c(X),fail.` *must* fails because he has `fail` component  .

At the 1st code sample  -  the checking starts on `1` , the component `b(1)` satisfied and after that it get to `!` , therefore no more optional checking would execute .

For more clarification about the `cut`  , you can examine putting the `!` at end of `a(X) :- b(X),!,c(X),fail.`

like this  -

```
a(X) :- b(X),c(X),fail,!.
a(X) :- d(X).

b(1).
b(4).
c(1).
c(3).

d(4).
```

And now  -

```
?- a(X).
X = 4.
```

Because the `fail` is before the `!` so the `!` is *unreachable* therefore the `cut` does not affect and still another optional taking account .

**Edit :**

The `fail` is relevant only for the rule he written there   , so `a(X) :- b(X),c(X),fail,!.` would forever causes the failure , but not the `a(X) :- d(X).` rule  .

Answer (score 0):

```
a(X) :- b(X),c(X),fail.
a(X) :- d(X).

b(1).
b(4).
c(1).
c(3).

d(4).

a(X). 
X = 4


a(X) :- b(X),!,c(X).
a(X) :- d(X).

b(1).
b(4).
c(1).
c(3).

d(4).

a(X).
X = 1

a(X) :- b(X),!,c(X),fail.
a(X) :- d(X).

b(1).
b(4).
c(1).
c(3).

d(4).

a(X).
false
```

Comment: I would be nice if you could add some explanation to your answer.